# Передача файлов по UDP

Tags: c#, filestream, udp

[Передача файлов по UDP](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level4/4_8.php)

Как разбить файлы на куски?

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два варианта.

- Перед отправкой файла указывайте на сколько частей он разбит
- При отправке каждой части указывайте последняя ли она

На клиенте, соответственно, просто склеиваете части.

Comment: а как собственно делить файл?

Comment: @nuka93: если у вас возникают такие вопросы, вам рано заниматься такими задачами.

Comment: я тоже так думаю, ну мне задали такое задание, не отвертеться

Comment: Кроме того, UDP не гарантирует порядок доставки датаграмм, поэтому необходимо включать номер пакета.

Comment: @nuka93: Ох. Задание. Ну ладно.

Смотрите, вам не нужно бить файл на части физически. Вам нужно лишь знать для каждой из частей, с какого байта она начинается и какой длины. При отправке нужной части соответственно отправляете не весь файл, а нужный кусок.

И обратите внимание на правильный комментарий о негарантированном порядке доставки, и вообще о негарантированной доставке. То есть клиент должен подтверждать серверу получение, и сервер должен при необходимости повторять отсылку данных. Геморно, да, но это UDP. TCP было бы лучше.

Comment: согласен, TCP было бы намного легче. Смещение байтов делать в методе Read ?

Comment: @nuka93: Ну, в `SendFile` вам надо читать только нужный кусок. Наверное, какие-то переметры команды `Read`. И в `SendFileInfo` тоже добавить информацию о куске, который вы отсылаете. А ещё надо в самом начале отослать информацию о том, сколько кусков будет. Ну и не забывайте о том, что куски имеют право не дойти.

Answer (score -1):

К Вашему запросу добавить заголовок 
Range: bytes=0-500 скачивает первые 500 бит
Range: bytes=500-filesize докачивает начиная с 500 бит
Так же нужна проверка, разрешен ли данный заголовок сервером

Comment: Речь идёт о UDP, а не HTTP.